# How can you get to Munich city centre from MUC terminal 2 and how long does it take?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, munich

I have few hours layover at the Munich airport and I'd like to go to the city centre.

My first flight arrives at 10.00 and the second one departs at 15.25, all local times. I am an Bulgarian citizen, so I guess there will be no issues with travel documents. I am generally looking for public transport means.

How can one get there from Terminal 2 and how long does that take?

Comment: Do you mean by public transport or taxi? How much time do you have exactly between flights? What time of the day would it be? Are you arriving from within Schengen or will you need to pass immigration for your arriving and your departing flight? See this question for an example: [Exactly 5hr 25min in Frankfurt, can I visit the city?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/73683/32134)

Comment: Just updated the question a bit, had a look at the other question as well, but I'd like to know what's the case with Munich airport, if possible.

Comment: @mts as an EU citizen, Phantomazi should not lose more than a couple of minutes to entry/exit checks, if they are needed.  That has at least been my experience at MUC, traveling mostly on summer weekends.  There would be at least one additional security check, I suppose, which would likely take 5-10 minutes if my experience is any guide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Munich airport (both terminals) is [well connected to the city center](http://www.munich-airport.com/en/consumer/anab/bahn/index.jsp) by train. The S1 and S8 S-Bahn lines stop at the airport, just follow the signs after baggage claim. They run every 10 minutes and will take you to München Hbf, the main train station. Or get off the S8 slightly earlier at Marienplatz, which will put you right in the middle of the city center.

You can explore Marienplatz and perhaps walk from there a short distance to the Viktualienmarkt or the destination of your choice.

The S8 [from the airport to Marienplatz](https://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query2.exe/en?ld=15085&protocol=https:&seqnr=6&ident=7b.03234185.1468959453&rt=1&rememberSortType=minDeparture&) will take 38 minutes, 49 minutes if you catch the S1 instead. Based on Google Maps, a car will likely take a similar amount of time without traffic and could take considerably longer if there is traffic. Just take the train in the opposite direction to get back to the airport.

As the airport is in the [outer fare zone](http://www.mvv-muenchen.de/fileadmin/media/Dateien/3_Tickets_Preise/dokumente/TARIFPLAN_Gesamtnetz_2016_mLEnglisch_ohneRinge.PDF), you'll need to buy a 4 zone ticket. A single trip [costs](http://www.mvv-muenchen.de/en/tickets-fares/tickets/single-trips/single-ticket/index.html) 10,80€, but a [day ticket](http://www.mvv-muenchen.de/en/tickets-fares/tickets/day-tickets/single-day-ticket/index.html) is available for 12,40€, which will get you there and back to the airport, plus any transport you desire in the city center.

Comment: The day ticket is also sold as Airport-City-Day-Ticket: "the Airport-City-Day-Ticket offers the same services as an MVV Day Ticket for the entire network, and at the same price".

Comment: +1 Worth adding that OP won't have that much time in the centre (1-2h max by my quick calcs) and should carefully plan when to return and weigh in possible delays, see my A on the Q I linked to.