# Is there a ranking or a guide with the airports offering the most beautiful landings?

Tags: air-travel, guides

Often landing (or take-off) offers very beautiful sights over travel destinations.

Knowing this would be a great way to start a travel. Unfortunately, I've lost this oportunity, several times for ignorance. One is either tired, focused on something else or just picked the wrong sit for that particular flight loosing the beautiful views.

**I was wondering if there is a ranking or a guide with the airports offering the most beautiful landings ?**

From such list I would expect information like what you can see. This probably is dependent on the landing/take off direction but such information could also be there.

I googled the question before posting here. There are many articles about it, but most offer a limited amount of airports (around 20); The information is a bit poor and the articles are more about showing pictures than actually giving real information.

[image: most beautiful landings]

Comment: On a very clear summer day there's nothing comparable to going into finals at Nuuk Airport. But that's an opinion, and quite probably all anyone else can offer.  So voting, sorry :(

Comment: There is nothing opinion-based about the question. A guide either is or isn't about beautiful landings, just like a guide either is or isn't about Rome or London. And such guides either exist or do not exist. If they do, there can't be many of them and they could certainly be listed in a comprehensive and completely objective answer. The fact that the author would be expressing value judgments in said guide is neither here nor there. I therefore voted to reopen the question.

Comment: I like that rationale, I have voted to reopen also

Comment: @pnuts  why is asking for a guide opinion based? Relaxed clarified the situation very well I would say.

Comment: @pnuts Beauty may be subjective, but the existence or nonexistence of a guide is factual.

Comment: Related: [Is there a resource about panoramic views at take-off/landing?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/71806/32134) (disclaimer: it's my Q)

Comment: @pnuts A very interesting question I might be prepared to debate at length in another context… but completely beside the point. Even if there was an indisputable quantitative measure of beauty, it still wouldn't answer the question asked by the OP. Similarly, the name of a beautiful airport isn't an answer to “Is there a guide about this?” so whether such a judgment would be opinion-based or not is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Complication: the "beauty" depends a lot on weather, time of day, which runway and which direction. BOS for example has six different landing directions and associated approaches. Coming in over the harbor islands at sunset is gorgeous. Coming in on rainy day over Everett and Chelsea is dull and boring.

Comment: Notice the headline **is there a GUIDE ....**  The question is, is there such a guide, or list.  It's a good question, I would love to know this.

Answer (score 4):

A friend of mine published his top five here: http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/27496732-post19.html

Answer (score 2):

Just to get the ball rolling, here's a **guide** to the most beautiful airports (per se) in the world ...

https://www.thrillist.com/home/the-most-beautiful-airports-in-the-world

so, that's not exactly what you're asking ("guide to most beautiful outlook as you land/takeoff") but it's a start.

Secondly, here's a major UK newspaper's list of exactly what you are asking,

*"The most beautiful airport approaches in the world..."*

http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-2998626/A-beach-Scotland-Colorado-runway-surrounded-14-000ft-peaks-tiny-tarmac-strip-Mustique-beautiful-airport-approaches-world.html

Finally here's a discussion by pilots on the issue ...

http://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=157237